# How to skip or avoid an Android API level in the manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest

We're writing an Android app which we plan to make available on Android devices that have at least Froyo (API 8) installed up to Jelly Bean (API 16), but we don't want to offer it to API levels 12 and 13 now, which are Honeycomb 3.1 and 3.2, respectively.

Basically, we're just avoiding Android tablets. Is there any way to skip these OSes? Something with `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: Somebody explain the downvote? I believe this is a perfectly good question to ask about Android.

Comment: You owe me one for the support to reopen this question :P https://twitter.com/COD3BOY/status/230335698903896066

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to skip OSes :) Use [< compatible-screens >](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) in your manifest and restrict to what you support.

From the docs,

> Specifies each screen configuration with which the application is
>   compatible. Only one instance of the  element is
>   allowed in the manifest, but it can contain multiple 
>   elements. Each  element specifies a specific screen
>   size-density combination with which the application is compatible.

Example :

If your application is compatible with only small and normal screens, regardless of screen density, then you must specify eight different  elements, because each screen size has four different density configurations.  Here's what the manifest entry looks like if your application is compatible with only small and normal screens:

```
<manifest ... >
    ...
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

---

**EDIT :**  Clarification about why you should **NOT** use `<supports-screens>` instead of this solution.

If you use the `<supports-screens>` element when your application is not compatible with larger screens and set the larger screen size attributes to "false", then external services such as Google Play **do not apply filtering.** Your **application will still be available to larger screens**, but when it runs, it will not resize to fit the screen. Instead, the system will emulate a handset screen size (about 320dp x 480dp).

Bottom line :

> If you want to prevent your application from being downloaded on larger screens, use `<compatible-screens>`

Comment: Yes, I just commented that one. Whoever took this whole switching of answers personally was really cruel, though. She literally went to my profile and downvoted my answers without providing any reason why.

Comment: @matkiros I just went to your profile and saw that :( down-voting without saying the reason is really bad :| Whenever I down-vote,its for a reason, I comment the reason, and take special attention to remove the down-vote after its corrected!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip application for tablets you can set largeScreenSupport and extraLargeScreenSupport to false in Manifest file.

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens="false"
                  />
```

Comment: THEN WAT ABOUT THE LARGE-SCREENS IN API 14 AND ABOVE ?

Comment: @AshokD, I'm very grateful for your sincerity to help, but buy a new keyboard, please. :)

Comment: thanks Buddy for give kind suggestion. By the way, I m using iMac.

Comment: @matkiros `<supports-screens>` cannot filter out large screens,it only lets you specify the screen sizes your application supports and enable screen compatibility mode for screens larger than what your application supports. `<compatible-screens>` is the way to go.

Comment: @jeet If so what is the difference between `<supports-screens>` and `<compatible-screens>` ?

Comment: @jeet I'm afraid Sanjay's answer is the correct one. `<compatible-screens>` dictates which screen sizes you support, and anything not included will be filtered out by services such as the Google Play Store. `<supports-screens>`, on the other hand, only tells the app for which screens to scale but DOES NOT filter the app out of the Play Store. For example, setting `xlargeScreens` to false means it'll simply emulate a normal screen size even in a tablet. Source, at the "Caution" part: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps

Comment: @jeet Please see my answer for clarification.

Comment: @matkiros if you are indicating me, that I am downvoting your answers, then I am not, you can ask moderators, I think they can help you to find who is doing this downvoting.

Comment: Apologies Sanjay and @jeet if I implied the two of you, you've only been very helpful towards getting to the answer. It's just that the switching of answers is the only reason I can think of for the long chain of down votes, which isn't illegal around here anyway. I'll just contact the moderators. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**MAY BE, THAT COULD NOT BE POSSIBLE FOR ANY DECLARATION IN MANIFEST FILE. YOU MUST HAVE TO CHECK THAT VERSION IN CODING IF YOU DONT WANT TO USE IT. **

Comment: See my answer for a possible way :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar query, this is what worked for me:

- Google Play allows you to publish two APK's with different SDK ranges.
- All the stats are combined for both your APK's when it's published.

  So i'm saying if you have to exclude API Level 12 & 13 you can
- make one APK with the range min(1) max(11)
- make the other APK with the range min(14) [which automatically means 14 or higher].

Comment: I did ask the same question here before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388911/should-i-create-multiple-versions-of-my-app-for-different-android-api-levels and I ultimately learned that making more than one APK for your app can give you maintenance problems from hell.